# Answer lock says it's a question lock

Tags: bug, status-completed

This answer is locked https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1997/3350. However, the lock says it's a question lock: [image: lock]

Comment: The historical lock wasn't really designed for use on a specific answer.

Comment: Either way, it's a bug.

Comment: IIRC, similar wording exists in the others.  A simple fix would be to replace "question" (or "answer", if that shows up anywhere) with "post", since questions and answers are both posts and only posts can have post notices.

Comment: Anyone know if this happens on all SE sites?

Comment: I've seen it on another site.  Those annotations are standard across SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, that's bad, not only from a display standpoint, but also from the back-end, which expects only questions to be locked with historical significance.

So, I've removed the ability to lock answers as historically significant, which was probably used to keep them from being flagged.  To help combat new flags on locked posts, only the "other" reason will be available.

As for the answer you linked, I removed the historical significance lock and relocked it without a notice.  Mods, feel free to make changes to that :)

Comment: The "'other' flags only on locked posts" functionality will be available after the next build.

Comment: That's interesting; "other" doesn't generate an annotation UI thingie, just a "locked" notice like for deletions?  I hadn't noticed that before (or is that new?).